# HTTPS not working if domain configured with another apache port into xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

I have hosted website with a different port like http://example.com:8888
Its working fine but when I try to access with HTTPS(https://example.com:8888) it's giving me ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR (This site can’t provide a secure connection)

I am using XAMPP and I have also configured an SSL certificate.

Please help me to configure with HTTPS.

Comment: We need more info to assist you. There is no way to assist you with the info provided currently. Show your virtualhosts and httpd.conf on your question. See: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable ssl in the VH listening on the new port

```
SSLEngine On
```

and you have to provide all the proper configurations required such as the keyfile, and the certificate file.
Official doc: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: it's working on a new listening port. https://example.com:8889 but when I want to port remain same after domain:8888

Comment: you can create a dedicated virtualhost for that specific domain listening on the port you want and then enable the SSL. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html